# Android - Exoplayer 2 - play multiple sounds/audio simultaneously - MergingMediaSource

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm using in my app several instances of `SimpleExoPlayer` to play audio file (Wav file). I want play all these files simultaneously. Now there is some small gap between these files. Is it possible to have only one instance of `SimpleExoPlayer` with more sounds files?

I tried use `MergingMediaSource` but it's now working. It's playing only one Wav file (not all).

Code:

```
        MediaSource ms = new MergingMediaSource(audioSources.toArray(new MediaSource[audioSources.size()]));
        mMediaPlayerTracker1.addListener(myExoPlayerEventListener);
        mMediaPlayerTracker1.prepare(ms);

        //Adding MediaSource to the ArrayList
        audioSources.add(new ExtractorMediaSource(
                    Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), mediaDataSourceFactory, defaultExtractorsFactory,
                    mainHandler, exoEventListener));
```

Comment: I am also curious to know if merging multiple "video" tracks together with MergingMediaSource. (If one video track contains alpha so that it can behave like an overlay on top of another).

Comment: @jclova did you find any solution?

Comment: did any solution has been found?

Comment: did you get any solution?